# Create password reset userflow in powershell: Azure b2c?

Tags: powershell, azure-authentication, azure-rest-api, azure-ad-b2c

I am creating Password reset user flow for my b2c users. From portal, I can create like this:

[image]

Is it supported to do the same from powershell or rest api?

I tried checking most of the graph v1.0 docs but I found nothing related to b2c. I want to implement this to avoid doing it manually from the portal.

Can anyone help me out with commands if they exist? If not, is there any other way possible to achieve this?

TIA

Comment: Found this at last: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/identitycontainer-post-b2cuserflows?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=powershell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got the below results:***

I created an Azure AD B2C application and granted API permissions like below:

Make sure to grant **`IdentityUserFlow.ReadWrite.All`** permission:

[image]

***I generated an access token via Postman by using client_credentials flow by using below Parameters:***

```json
https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantID/oauth2/v2.0/token

client_id=Your_client_ID
client_secret=Your_client_Secret
grant_type=client_credentials
scope=https://graph.microsoft.com/.default
```

**Response:**

[image]

*By using the above generated access token, **open a new tab in Postman and include the parameters** like below:*

In **Authorization tab**, select Type as Bearer Token and paste the access token like below:

[image]

In the Header tab, add **`Content-type: application/json`**  and In the **Body tab** add like below:

```json
 {
"id": "testuserflow",
"userFlowType": "passwordReset",
"userFlowTypeVersion": 3
}
```

[image]

**By using the below Endpoint run the query and user flow will be created successfully like below:**

```json
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/identity/b2cUserFlows
```

[image]

**In the Azure Portal, the testuserflow is successfully created like below:**

[image]